# How to get url like support.appname.com in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Currently the default_url_option is set as

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'app.lvh.me:3000'
```

on development environment.

The problem I am having here with the route is to get support.appname.com.

Tried solution

```
get 'support.appname.com' => 'supports#index'
```

But it returns with app.lvh.me:3000/support.appname.com as expected.
Is there a way I could get support.appname.com or support.app.lvh.me:3000 (support.appname.com in production) to redirect to SupportsController#index?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to enable subdomain support in your code. Can you try the following in your routes.rb file.

```
resources :supports, constraints: { subdomain: 'support' }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.rb` add

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    (request.subdomain.present?) && (request.subdomain(1) == "support")
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(AppSubdomain) do
   get 'support' => "support#index"
 end
end
```

Now if you access `support.appname.com/support` it will be routed to the `index` action of `Support` controller